# How to Load SVG Image in Flutter Without Internet and No Cached Network using SvgPicture.network?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a Flutter project and need to display an SVG image using the SvgPicture.network widget from the flutter_svg package. However, I need a solution for scenarios where there is no internet connection, and the image is not cached. How can I gracefully handle this situation and display an SVG image even when there's no internet access or the image is not cached?

SvgPicture.network(
"",
width: 193,
height: 193,
)

Answer (score 0):

Use `connectivity_plus` to check internet.

```
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';

bool isInternetAvailable = false;
@override
initState() {
checkInternet();
super.initState();
}
void checkInternet() async {
final connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());

if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
  // I am connected to a mobile network.
  isInternetAvailable = true;
} else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
  // I am connected to a wifi network.
  isInternetAvailable = true;
} else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.ethernet) {
  // I am connected to a ethernet network.
  isInternetAvailable = true;
} else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.vpn) {
  isInternetAvailable = true;
} else {
 isInternetAvailable = false;
}
setState((){});
}
```

Then...

```
isInternetAvailable ? SvgPicture.network(
//add needed properties
) : SvgPicture.asset(
  //add needed properties
 )
```

There is listener in `connectivity_plus` package you can check it out to continuously listen to internet status too.

Comment: but I am getting the image from api which starts with https and SvgPicture.asset will not works in this case

Comment: @ibtissam it will never work without internet. If you can't access the cached file or have it as local asset, without internet you can't access a file that is on a server.

Comment: yes I know but for example for .png images we use CachedNetworkImage which shows the images without internet, how to achieve that with svg images ? is there a way ?

Comment: I found the solution by download the file using cacheManager package then show the downloaded file that stored in cache when there is no internet, thank you